# is it possible to use Tensorflow js custom model from local file in react native?

Tags: android, react-native, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am trying to use a custom Tensorflow.js model in react native using React Native CLI.

It seems that [@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native) is not maintained anymore. When I try to install it based on the instructions provided on the official GitHub page, I face many dependency conflicts that are impossible to resolve. So this fact renders the package useless.

Also, tflite is not an option either based on the nature of my model(Details are irrelevant, though I would gladly explain if it would help in solving my problem). But even if I wanted to use that format, I doubt it would work because the package available for that also looks deprecated considering it was last updated around 3 years ago.

And for the same reason(Model's Nature), despite having a fully updated package, ONNX is currently not an option either.

So that leaves me with Tensorflow.js. And I should mention that I know the hardware limitations involved in using this too.

So my question is, considering the things I've said above, is there a way to use Tensorflow.js meaning [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tensorflow/tfjs) package in react native, and load a custom model to make predictions?
or should I just give up? If yes, please do share a simple working piece of code.

Also, my model is a Keras model saved in Tensorflow.js format. Finally, I also tried loading a model from a URL but no luck there too(Note that I am not trying to imply that it is impossible, I am merely saying that I was not able to do it. Would be awesome if you could tell me a way to do that too if possible of course.)

Thanks in advance for your time. If there is anything unclear, tell and I will try to elaborate more.

Comment: tensorflow/tfjs-react-native is still being actively maintained. But if you really can't get it to work, you can try to create a python server that contains the model and make RN request the prediction over to the server as your last resort.

Comment: @caslawter Yes, that is what I had in mind as the alternative but it would have been so good if I could have made predictions on the phone because the software I am developing might be used in a place where there is no internet connection. Thanks for your time.